# Pressure affect of electronic resistance of plants

Tags: pressure, electrical-resistance

I have a electronic circuit that goes through a plant to measure its resistance. Therefor I put a cable in the soil. Then I have conductive thread on a little thimble that sits on my index finger. 
When I touch the plant with my index finger, I'm closing the circuit. This works well.

I'm now using a voltage divider to measure the resistance (or the amount of current that goes through). 
The problem is, it strongly depends on the pressure I put with my index finger on the plant. I was expecting, that I can measure different resistances based on how far the current has to flow through the plant. Lower resistance on the bottom, higher resistance on the top of it. This is now hardly to say because of the pressure fluctuation.

Is this just normal? Is maybe the conductive thread responsible? If it is normal, would there be ways to prevent that?

I'm sorry if that question doesn't fit here, please let me know.
Do appreciate every hint in the right direction.

Thanks a lot.
Marcel

Answer (score 0):

This is usually called pressure contact resistance and is normal (You'll find info rather easy), i.e., in general the resistance depends on contact pressure. 
If suitable try to use a needle and penetrate the plant. (OK from the physics point of view, not sure if this is true from the biology point of view)

Answer (score 0):

There are many factors that will affect the flow of current through the plant.

Pressure of your finger is one of them. As you apply more pressure you will create a wider contact area between the plant and the thimble; the wider the contact area the lower the resistance.

If pressure breaks any of the plant's cells then you make contact with the conductive sap of the plant, and resistance will drop further. Again, this depends on the amount of cell damage.

Another factor you have not mentioned is the resistance between the electrode and the soil. The deeper the electrode goes in the soil, and the wetter the soil is, the lower the resistance between soil and electrode, and hence between the soil and your finger.

The height of the plant (or the height above ground of the point of contact) and the diameter of its stems is another factor to consider. All in all, this is an experiment that will rarely give repeatable results.